# Lucene index: getting empty result while query

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, jackrabbit-oak

I am trying to query with Lucene index but getting the empty result and below errors in the log,

```
Traversal query (query without index): select [jcr:path] from [nt:base] where isdescendantnode('/test') and name='World'; consider creating an index


[async] The index update failed
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakAsync0002: Missing index provider detected for type [counter] on index [/oak:index/counter]
```

I am using RDB DocumentStore and I have checked index and node are created in nodes table.i tried below code,

```
   @Autowired 
   NodeStore rdbNodeStore;

   //create reposiotory
   LuceneIndexProvider provider = new LuceneIndexProvider();
   ContentRepository repository = new Oak(rdbNodeStore)
                .with(new OpenSecurityProvider())
                .with(new InitialContent())
                .with((QueryIndexProvider) provider)
                .with((Observer) provider)
                .with(new LuceneIndexEditorProvider())
                .withAsyncIndexing("async", 
   5).createContentRepository();

    //login reposiotory and retrive session
    ContentSession contentSession = repository.login(null, null);
    Root root = contentSession.getLatestRoot();

    //create lucene index
      Tree index = root.getTree("/");

      Tree t = index.addChild("oak:index");

      t = t.addChild("lucene");
      t.setProperty("jcr:primaryType", "oak:QueryIndexDefinition", Type.NAME);
      t.setProperty("compatVersion", Long.valueOf(2L), Type.LONG);
      t.setProperty("type", "lucene", Type.STRING);
      t.setProperty("async", "async", Type.STRING);

      t = t.addChild("indexRules");
      t = t.addChild("nt:base");
      Tree propnode = t.addChild("properties");
      Tree t1 = propnode.addChild("name");
      t1.setProperty("name", "name");
      t1.setProperty("propertyIndex", Boolean.valueOf(true), Type.BOOLEAN);
      root.commit();

      //Create TestNode
      String h = "Hello" + System.currentTimeMillis();
      String w = "World" + System.currentTimeMillis();

      Tree test = root.getTree("/").addChild("test");
      test.addChild("a").setProperty("name", Arrays.asList(new String[] { h, w }), Type.STRINGS);
      test.addChild("b").setProperty("name", h);
      root.commit();

      //Search
      String query = "select [jcr:path] from [nt:base] where isdescendantnode('/test') and name='World' option(traversal ok)";

      List<String> paths = executeQuery(root, query, "JCR-SQL2", true, false);
      for (String path : paths) {
        System.out.println("Path=" + path);
      }
```

can anyone share some sample code on how to create Lucene index?

Comment: Could you share how are you initializing the repository. The error seems to indicate that you, at least, haven't provisioned some index editors.

Comment: @catholicon, Please check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with what you're likely doing. First thing would the error that you're observing. Since you're using `InitialContent` which provisions an index with `type="counter"`. For that you'd need to have `.with(new NodeCounterEditorProvider())` while building the repository. That should avoid the error you are seeing.

But, your code would likely still not work because lucene indexes are async (which you've correctly configured). Due to that asynchronous behavior, you can't query immediately after adding the node.
I tried your code but had to add something like `Thread.sleep(10*1000)` before going for querying.

As another side-note, I'd recommend that you try out `IndexDefinitionBuilder` to make lucene index structure. So, you could replace
    Tree index = root.getTree("/");

```
Tree t = index.addChild("oak:index");

t = t.addChild("lucene");
t.setProperty("jcr:primaryType", "oak:QueryIndexDefinition", Type.NAME);
t.setProperty("compatVersion", Long.valueOf(2L), Type.LONG);
t.setProperty("type", "lucene", Type.STRING);
t.setProperty("async", "async", Type.STRING);

t = t.addChild("indexRules");
t = t.addChild("nt:base");
Tree propnode = t.addChild("properties");
Tree t1 = propnode.addChild("name");
t1.setProperty("name", "name");
t1.setProperty("propertyIndex", Boolean.valueOf(true), Type.BOOLEAN);
root.commit();
```

with

```
IndexDefinitionBuilder idxBuilder = new IndexDefinitionBuilder();
idxBuilder.indexRule("nt:base").property("name").propertyIndex();
idxBuilder.build(root.getTree("/").addChild("oak:index").addChild("lucene"));
root.commit();
```

The latter approach, imo, is less error prone and more redabale.

Comment: can you help me out, I am not able to create a repository with new NodeCounterEditorProvider() still facing the issue with counter index. can you share me working example of oak repository creation with Lucene index?

Comment: @sandy, see pastebin.com/08z3EZ9G as a test case that outputs Path=/test/a. Maybe you can spot what's missing.

Comment: i am getting                                                                                                            
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Traversal query (query without index): select [jcr:path] from [nt:base] where isdescendantnode('/test') and name='World' option(traversal fail); consider creating an index
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl.verifyNotPotentiallySlow(QueryImpl.java:1226)

Comment: @sandy, this is getting out of scope for stack overflow imo. Maybe you should drop a mail to oak-dev@jackrabbit.apache.org with logs that you have and the code that you used.