# How to create RDBMS oak repository with lucene index

Tags: java, apache, indexing, lucene, jackrabbit-oak

Can anyone share an example of initializing RDBMS Oak Repository with Lucene Index?

I have tried below but getting

```
The index update failed
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakAsync0002: Missing index provider detected for type [counter] on index [/oak:index/counter] error
```

```
LuceneIndexProvider provider = new LuceneIndexProvider();

                repository = new Oak(documentNodeStoreService)
            .with(new InitialContent())
                        .with(new OpenSecurityProvider())
            .with((QueryIndexProvider) provider)
            .with((Observer) provider)
                        .with(new LucenePropertyInitialiser("testluceneIndex", of("^[^\\/]*$")))
                        .with(new LuceneIndexEditorProvider())
                        .with(new NodeCounterEditorProvider())
                        .withAsyncIndexing("async", 5)
            .with("custom")
            .createContentRepository();
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655489?